# SQL After aggregation and join. Display the Not Equal value and The NULLs

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregate

***UPDATED :***

I am try to achieve this,

```
TBL1
PK     AK     TOT1
1      1      100  
2      2      200
3      3      300

TBL2
PK     AK     TOT2
1      1      50
2      1      50
3      2      150
```

First of, I aggregate the TBL2 which is, all of the TBL2.AK(1) is summed.
Then use JOIN to display them.

The script is like this,

```
SELECT t1.AK, t1.TOT1, t2.TOT1
FROM TBL1 t1
    JOIN (SELECT AK, SUM(TOT1) as TOT1
    FROM TBL2
    GROUP BY AK) t2
ON t1.AK = t2.AK
WHERE t1.TOT1 <> t2.TOT1
```

It displays tables where t1.TOT1 <> t2.TOT1.

But as of now, my problem is,

i.e.
  TBL1.AK has a value of (3) but TBL2.AK has not.
I need also to display them.

as of now, I am adding the

```
LEFT JOIN
```

and adding the

```
WHERE t1.AK IS NULL OR t2.AK IS NULL.
```

Still no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is performing an inner join; it's returning only rows that have matching values.

You are correct, to also get rows from one table that do *not* have a matching row in the other table, you would need an "outer" join.

To get the result you describe:

1) add the keyword `FULL` before the `JOIN` keyword, and

<strike>2) relocate the predicate in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause</strike>

2) the predicate in the `WHERE` clause also needs to allow for rows with NULL value for t1.TOT1 or t2.TOT1 to be returned

---

In the `WHERE` clause, the condition `t1.TOT1 <> t2.TOT1` will negate the "outerness" of the join.  For any rows returned from `t1` that don't have a matching row from `t2`, the expression `t2.TOT` will evaluate to NULL, and the inequality comparison will evaluate to NULL. And that will prevent the row from being returned.

The bare `JOIN` keyword is an "inner" join. To get an outer join, that has to be preceded by a keyword `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `FULL`.  To allow the "non-matching" rows to be returned, the `WHERE` clause must not prohibit those rows from being returned.

---

For example

```
SELECT t1.AK
     , t1.TOT1
     , t2.TOT1
  FROM TBL1 t1
  FULL
  JOIN ( SELECT AK
             , SUM(TOT1) AS TOT1
          FROM TBL2
         GROUP BY AK
       ) t2
    ON t1.AK = t2.AK
 WHERE t1.TOT1 <> t2.TOT1
    OR (t1.TOT1 IS     NULL AND t2.TOT1 IS NOT NULL)
    OR (t1.TOT1 IS NOT NULL AND t2.TOT1 IS     NULL)
```

In this form, the query would return the rows

```
AK     t1.TOT1  t2.TOT1    
3      300      NULL
NULL   NULL     400
```

If you want to return the value "4" as the value of the AK column on that last row, you would need a different expression in the SELECT list, e.g.

```
SELECT NVL(t1.AK,t2,AK) AS AK
```

or the more ANSI standards equivalent

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.AK IS NOT NULL t1.AK ELSE t2.AK END AS AK
```

Comment: Thanks, I see the point where in using [WHERE] negats the "outerness" of the join. But based on your answer, Adding [AND] next to [ON] also negates the the [ON] clause (just my opinion). As I see, the [AND t1.TOT1 <> t2.TOT1] does not detect anymore the [SUM(TOT)] I created even there is a value, it displays "NULL"

Comment: @MaCheeNeraid: In the `ON` clause, the `t1.TOT1<>t2.TOT1` condition determines whether a row from the table on the left "matches" a row from the table on the right.  In the case where the table on left returns (5,100) and the table on the right returns (5,250), then both of those rows will be returned. For the row returned from the left side, the value of `t1.AK` will be NULL. To get `t2.AK` displayed, you need an expression in the SELECT list that will display that.

Comment: @MaCheeNeraid: I understand what you were saying... the query in my answer is returning two rows for AK=1. One of them from the left side, the other from the right side.  SQLFiddle demonstration here:  [**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d5d0/3**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d5d0/3).  (Moving the condition to the `ON` clause of a FULL join does *not* return the specified result.  That condition does need to be in the WHERE clause, but the condition needs to allow for rows with NULL values to be returned.

Comment: I tried the code you posted above, based on the TBLs I created, it display the AK=1 [TBL1.TOT1 = 100] [TBL2.TOT1 = NULL]. I wonder why the TBL2.TOT value became null after that?

Comment: @MaCheeNeraid: I've edited my answer.  My original query returned a NULL for `t2.TOT1` because the condition in the WHERE clause prevented the row from t2 from "matching". The outer join returned a row with NULL values for the t2 columns as a substitute for the matching row. I think of it this way...  in an outer join, when a matching row is not found, then a row of "all null" values is substituted, and returned in place of a matching row.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The OR (t1.TOT1 IS     NULL AND t2.TOT1 IS NOT NULL) does its job. Though I edited the TOT1 part since what I need to know is if the TBL1.AK is existing in TBL2.AK. But still, you hit it right in the pocket. :D Very Thanks Buddy.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE t1.AK IS NULL OR t2.AK IS NULL OR t1.TOT1 <> t2.TOT1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what would you want to display because you sum data in only a table but I suggest like this.

For query all of record in both table. Just like this.

```
SELECT *  -- Display as you want
FROM TBL1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN TBL2 t2
ON t1.AK = t2.AK
```

If you need to merge data of AK in both table as a column. you can use [NVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm)

```
SELECT NVL(t1.AK,t2.AK)   --if t1.AK value is null, it will display t2.AK value.
FROM TBL1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN TBL2 t2
ON t1.AK = t2.AK
```

If you need to "group by" and sum values, you can do like this.

```
SELECT NVL(t1.AK,t2.AK),  
       SUM(t1.TOT1),
       SUM(t2.TOT2)
FROM TBL1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN TBL2 t2
ON t1.AK = t2.AK 
GROUP BY NVL(t1.AK,t2.AK)
```

Edited: Maybe you need this below.

```
SELECT NVL(t1.AK,t2.AK),  
       t1.TOT1,
       t2.TOT1
FROM TBL1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT AK, SUM(TOT2) AS TOT1
                 FROM TBL1 2
                 GROUP BY AK) t2
ON t1.AK = t2.AK 
WHERE t1.TOT1 <> t2.TOT1
GROUP BY NVL(t1.AK,t2.AK)
```

Comment: The value returned by the expression `SUM(t1.TOT1)` will be a multiple of the value of `t1.TOT1` returned by the OP query, in the case when `TBL2` has multiple rows with the same value of AK... e.g. AK=1 in OP example data. This query also does not exclude rows where the values of TOT1 are equal.